# Normalized cuts with Matlab 2013a

Tags: matlab, image-processing, cluster-analysis, image-segmentation, arpack

I am using the normalized cuts package from http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jshi/software/Ncut_9.zip
(on Windows 7)

This used to work fine with Matlab2010a. However I have upgraded to Matlab2013a (32 bit student version) and I now get the following error:

```
Error using arpackc
Expect 2 output arguments

Error in eigs_new (line 240)
        arpackc( aupdfun, ido, ...

Error in ncut (line 83)
[vbar,s,convergence] =
eigs_new(@mex_w_times_x_symmetric,size(P,1),nbEigenValues,'LA',options,tril(P));

Error in ncutW (line 9)
[NcutEigenvectors,NcutEigenvalues] =
ncut(W,nbcluster);

Error in NcutImage (line 18)
[NcutDiscrete,NcutEigenvectors,NcutEigenvalues]
= ncutW(W,nbSegments);

Error in demoNcutImage (line 25)
[SegLabel,NcutDiscrete,NcutEigenvectors,NcutEigenvalues,W,imageEdges]=
NcutImage(I,nbSegments);
```

Obviously the `new_eigs()` function in `ncuts` is incompatible with the ARPACK version in the latest Matlab.

- Does anybody know of a workaround for this?
- Normalised uses a modified version of Matlab's `eigs()` function. Why can't I just use Matlab's built-in `eigs()` instead of `eigs_new()` (it does seem to work).

Comment: can you explain why `eigs()` does not work for you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two solutions to this:

1. Use Matlab's `eigs()` function instead of the `eigs_new()` provided in the normalized cuts package. I guess `eigs_new()` was designed to solve some compatibility issue with a previous version of Matlab, and is now itself causing an issue.
2. Modify `eigs_new()`. Where there is a call to `arpackc()` in `eigs_new()`, make the call like in the tool box version of `eigs()`.
   So, e.g.:

   ```
   arpackc( aupdfun, ido, ...
    bmat, intconvert(n), whch, nev, tol, resid, ncv, ...
       v, ldv, iparam, ipntr, workd, workl, lworkl, info );
   ```

becomes

```
    [ido, info] = arpackc( aupdfun, ido, bmat, intconvert(n), whch, ...
        nev, tol, resid, ncv, v, ldv, iparam, ipntr, workd, workl, ...
        lworkl, info );
```

There were only two places where this had to be changed to make it work (although there other calls to `arpackc()` which don't actually get executed).

I am still not sure why `eigs_new()` exists at all.

Answer (score 6):

In matlab2014a 64bit windows,
you only change

```
[vbar,s,convergence] = eigs_new(@mex_w_times_x_symmetric,size(P,1),nbEigenValues,'LA',options,tril(P));
```

in line 81 of ncut.m
into

```
[vbar,s,convergence] = eigs(@mex_w_times_x_symmetric,size(P,1),nbEigenValues,'LA',options,tril(P));
```

and then eigs_new.m is useless which don't care.
Becaus in 2014 (or more than 2009 ) arpackc has been replaced with eigs.
And you can read the help of eigs for more help.

Answer (score 0):

I used to work with this code a while ago. For 32-64 bit issues I made some changes. I also changed this `eigs_new` line into

```
[vbar,s,convergence] = eigs2(@mex_w_times_x_symmetric,size(P,1),nbEigenValues,'LA',options,tril(P));
```

Should work...

Comment: There doesn't seem to an eigs2() in my version of Matlab, so this unfortunately doesn't help.

Comment: @user2151446 try http://www.oifii.org/ns-org/nsd/ar/cp/music_marsyas-0.4.5/marsyas-0.4/marsyas-0.4.5/scripts/MATLAB/peakExtraction/ncut/eigs2.m

Comment: Thanks, however this version of eigs2() has the same incompatibility with arpackc() in Matlab2013a as eigs_new()